# How can I get the Rock to Fall upon the player colliding with the trigger box BELOW the rock

Tags: c#, xna

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    int dt = gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
    base.Update(gameTime);

    player.storedPos = player.position;
    Vector3 storedAcc = acceleration;
    acceleration = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) player.rotation.Y += 0.1f;
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) player.rotation.Y -= 0.1f;

    player.velocity *= 0.9f; // friction

    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
    {
       acceleration.X = (float)Math.Sin(player.rotation.Y) * 0.001f;
       acceleration.Z = (float)Math.Cos(player.rotation.Y) * 0.001f;
    }

    // camera follow
    gamecam.position = new Vector3(50, 50, 50) + player.position;
    gamecam.target = player.position;

    MovePlayer(dt);

    foreach (basicCuboid WallSegment in walls)
    {
        if (player.hitBox.Intersects(WallSegment.collisionbox))
        {
            ElasticCollision(WallSegment);
        }
    }
    if (player.hitBox.Intersects(door.collisionbox))
    {
        ElasticCollision(door);
    }

    if (player.hitBox.Intersects(TriggerBoxRockFall) && !rockFalling)
    {
        rockFalling = true;
        rock.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0.2f, 0);
    }

    if (rockFalling)
    {
        Vector3 gravity = new Vector3(0, -0.01f, 0);
    }
```

So this is the code I have so far, I am unsure about how to make the rock actually fall though. What am I missing or have I typed something in wrong? I need the rock to fall upon the player colliding with a trigger box below the rock.

Comment: It appears you are using a game framework of some kind.  Please add this as a tag to your question.  Otherwise this question will be very difficult to answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, its XNA

Comment: I need a little more information to understand what you're trying, perhaps a screenshot to have a visual idea what you meant. For example I'm not sure if the 'trigger box' is a pressure plate/button, or a square box to intersect with. Does the box needs to be inside, or just on top of it?

Comment: The trigger box is a square box the player will intersect with, the player just has to touch the box. The box is below the rock.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the code provided, but you only want the code for player.hitBox.Intersects(TriggerBoxRockFall) to trigger when you are below it.

Change the code:

```
if (player.hitBox.Intersects(TriggerBoxRockFall) && !rockFalling)
{
    rockFalling = true;
    rock.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0.2f, 0);
}
```

to:

```
if (player.Velocity.Y < 0 && player.hitBox.Intersects(TriggerBoxRockFall) && !rockFalling)
{
    rockFalling = true;
    rock.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0.2f, 0);
}
```

As a side note, move as much of the code out of Game1 as possible. The gravity of the rock should be done in the Rock, not Game1.

for example:

```
if (player.Velocity.Y < 0 && player.hitBox.Intersects(TriggerBoxRockFall) && !rockFalling)
{
    rockFalling = true;
    rock.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0.2f, 0);
    rock.GravityApplies = true;
}
```